# Telnet Session "Stuck" while in PuTTY

Tags: windows, putty, telnet

From within a PuTTY session, I have opened a telnet connection to another server successfully.

However, the escape character for telnet has not been set, so the telnet session reads: "Escape character is 'off'".

Using the CTRL+] combination, BREAK, special PuTTY commands, & other tricks have been unsuccessful in closing the telnet session.

What else can I do, potentially instead of closing/reopening PuTTY (which is an expensive operation for certain servers)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read many posts detailing possible "termination" keys to send telnet, but none worked.

The only working method I've found for this situation is to simply send a malformed request to the server, which depending on the protocol will cause the foreign host to terminate the connection.

For example, port 80 (HTTP), you can send a bad HTTP request like this:

```
GET /$#$ HTTP/1.1
HOST: www.mysite.com
<hit enter twice>
```